# Phrase after "there"

Tags: grammar

> There, reflected behind him, were at least ten others.

I am confused with this sentence. what reflected actually?  Can you explain this one?

Answer (score 3):

The "ten others" are being reflected, and the location of this reflection is "behind him".

There is probably a mirror or something similar for this reflection:

> There, reflected [in the mirror] behind him, were at least ten others.

---

Here are two other ways to write the sentence:

> At least ten others were there, reflected [in the mirror] behind him.

or

> Behind him, at least ten others were reflected [in the mirror].